# task_for_pid stops working on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, code-injection

I am using mach_inject to do some code injection work, but when I upgrade to the latest OS X 10.11 it stops working, and I trace that it's caused by failed execution of task_for_pid, return value is 5.
andy idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Check `/etc/authorization` to make sure your application is permitted to use `task_for_pid`. Other relevant keywords: `taskgated`.

Comment: @icktoofay Apple has depreciated /etc thing, and I man taskgated, According the man info It should be ok if I set SecTaskAccess and signed the code properly, unfortunately,  no luck. I feel Apple I have changed something but hasn't changed the documents in time. any way, thanks a lot, I've learned a lot from this info :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the [latest features](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html) of 10.11 is System Integrity Protection, aka 'rootless'.

As stated by Apple: -

> ## System Integrity Protection
>
> A new security policy that applies to every running process, including privileged code and code that runs out of the sandbox. The policy extends additional protections to components on disk and at run-time, only allowing system binaries to be modified by the system installer and software updates. **Code injection and runtime attachments to system binaries are no longer permitted.**

So there you have it, code-injection is no longer possible*. You can [disable this feature,](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) but to do so requires booting into Recovery Mode and using the csrutil command.

* Assuming you don't have a kernel extension!