# Get number of active threads spawned by current process on MacOS

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, macos, operating-system

I've been searching for the last 3 hours online and through system headers, but can not find a mechanism available to me in C/C++ for what I'm trying to do on MacOS.

I'm looking to find a way to retrieve for the currently running process the total number of active/alive threads. I acknowledge that this would be trivial if I were counting threads that I myself spawn, but this is not the case. The code base I'm working on uses several threading libraries, and I require this basic information for debugging purposes.

On linux I can just acces `/proc/self/stat/` where the 20th element is the total number of alive threads, but this is not available on MacOS. If it helps, this has to work on MacOS 12.0 +

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I can't find a way either.  I thought there might be some mileage in `kevent`, but, sadly, there isn't.  But the debugger (llvm) somehow knows about all the currently running threads and this is exposed graphically if you debug under Xcode.  Is that any use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a bit of googling around, it seems to me like you should be able to obtain this information using `task_threads()`, after getting the right mach port from `task_for_pid()`:

```
int pid = 123; // PID you want to inspect
mach_port_t me = mach_task_self();
mach_port_t task;
kern_return_t res;
thread_array_t threads;
mach_msg_type_number_t n_threads;

res = task_for_pid(me, pid, &task);
if (res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    // Handle error...
}

res = task_threads(task, &threads, &n_threads);
if (res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    // Handle error...
}

// You now have `n_threads` as well as the `threads` array
// You can use these to extract info about each thread

res = vm_deallocate(me, (vm_address_t)threads, n_threads * sizeof(*threads));
if (res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    // Handle error...
}
```

Note however that the usage of `task_for_pid()` might be restricted. I don't know much about how entitlements work on macOS, but you can check these other posts:

- [task_for_pid stops working on OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943275/task-for-pid-stops-working-on-os-x-10-11)
- [Getting task_for_pid() to work in El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468640/getting-task-for-pid-to-work-in-el-capitan)
- [This GitHub Gist containing an example with a commented `.plist`](https://gist.github.com/attilathedud/e58917c9fd095a84fd5bbfb31674be05)

Comment: Thank you. This 100% does what I wanted on MacOS 12

Comment: What if we don't want to deal with the security shenanigans? It's the current process, why do we need permission to ask about it?

Comment: @gps because Apple chose so. They are pretty paranoid about this kind of stuff. There's no way around it. If you don't want to deal with it, well... IDK, switch to Linux maybe? :')

Comment: I had access to a mac today, it appears to work fine with the current process without doing anything special.

Comment: Can confirm. Using the answer I accepted I do not get prompted to elevate the security clearance / bypass security for my application. This is true whether or not the application was built on my own machine or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified (C++) version of the answer from Marco Bonelli.
`task_for_pid` can be skipped if interested in the threads of the current process.

```
   #include <mach/mach.h>

   int getCurrentThreadCount()
   {
       auto me = mach_task_self();
       thread_array_t threads;
       mach_msg_type_number_t numberOfThreads;

       auto res = task_threads(me, &threads, &numberOfThreads);
       if (res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
           return -1;
       }

       res = vm_deallocate(me, (vm_address_t)threads, numberOfThreads * sizeof(*threads));
       if (res != KERN_SUCCESS) {
           return -1;
       }

       return numberOfThreads;
   }
```